# c# create or modify file/directory permission: add group read permission using asp.net with mono and apache2

Tags: c#, linux, mono, apache2, file-permissions

How can I change/set permissions of a file or directory using asp.net under mono and apache2?

I have an aspx page that needs to check if a directory exists, if not, it must be created, but with group read permissions set. Tried with `DirectorySecurity`, but it throws `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

Apache is using www-data user and all files/folders created are owned by this user, the directory permissions look like this `drwx------`.

The question is how they can be modified to `drwxr-----`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [Syscall.chmod](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aMono.Unix.Native.Syscall.chmod) from Mono.Unix.Native